# Использование Ozon Seller API на Дельфи с synapse

Tags: delphi

```
function doSellerAPI (client_id: string; api_key: string; var resultCode: integer;
  res: TStrings): boolean;
var
  http: THTTPSend;
begin
  http := THTTPSend.Create;
  try
    http.Protocol := '1.1';
    http.AddPortNumberToHost := false;
    http.UserAgent := '';
    http.KeepAlive := false;

    http.Headers.Add('Client-Id: ' + client_id);
    http.Headers.Add('Api-Key: ' + api_key);
    http.Headers.Add('Content-Type: application/json');

    Result := http.HTTPMethod('GET','https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v2/product/info');
    resultCode := http.ResultCode;
    res.LoadFromStream(http.Document);
  finally
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Возвращает код 405. Модули ssl_openssl, ssl_openssl_lib подключены в uses.

Использовал POST вместо GET и, вроде, заработало, несмотря на то, что документации на сайте по адресу https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/#section/Chto-takoe-rabochaya-sreda написано:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api-seller.ozon.ru
Client-Id: <Client-Id>
Api-Key: <Api-Key>
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: Где вы в документации увидели, что там GET? Вот тут написано, что POST: https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/#operation/ProductAPI_GetProductInfoV2

Comment: https://docs.ozon.ru/api/seller/#section/Chto-takoe-rabochaya-sreda Формат запроса

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api-seller.ozon.ru
Client-Id: <Client-Id>
Api-Key: <Api-Key>
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Там для каждого типа API запроса в доках приведён конкретный пример и указано, get там или post надо использовать (и что конкретно в теле post должно быть). А в самом начале, куда вы ссылаетесь, приведен общий вид запроса для общего понятия, какие поля в хидерах нужно указать. Короче, RTFM как всегда.

Comment: zed, в FM толком не описано как отправлять запросы плюс ошибка, так что пришлось потерять день на то, чтобы угадать подбором. А эти иконки рядом с запросами настолько плохо незаметны, что их не сразу найдешь, даже если знаешь что искать. При том, что к ним никаких пояснений нет. Нигде не написано - 'вид запроса get или post - это малозаметная иконка в левом верхнем углу". В общем, брак в работе автора FM.

Comment: Кстати, вместо техподдержки там отвечает тупой бот, который, естественно, даже не способен понять вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в использовании метода GET вместо метода POST.
При этом json надо передавать в теле запроса.